# In golang how can I write the stdout of an exec.Cmd to a file?

Tags: file-io, go

I am trying to run a shell command, capture stdout and write that output to a file. However, I seem to be missing a few steps, as the file I am trying to write is empty when the program exists. How can I capture the stdout of the command and write that to a file?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "'WHAT THE HECK IS UP'")

    // open the out file for writing
    outfile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer outfile.Close()

    stdoutPipe, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(outfile)

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go io.Copy(writer, stdoutPipe)
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to flush the writer. Add the following:

```
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(outfile)
    defer writer.Flush()
```

Comment: Duh, I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 53):

Thanks to KirkMcDonald on the `#go-nuts` irc channel, I solved this by assigning the output file to [`cmd.Stdout`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd), which means that stdout writes directly to the file. It looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "'WHAT THE HECK IS UP'")

    // open the out file for writing
    outfile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer outfile.Close()
    cmd.Stdout = outfile

    err = cmd.Start(); if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

Comment: This is really good. If you use `cmd.Run()` you do not need to issue the `cmd.Wait()` at the end since `Run` is blocking.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution: logs are not redirected to the file if I start the service via systemctl, instead, the logs are redirected to systemd's journal(using journal -u ${pid} to see this).

Answer (score 19):

You can also use:

```
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

which will redirect all cmd output to the OS' standard output.

Comment: "OS' standard output" is really the parent process' `stdout` not "the OS'".  Also, by default i.e. if the program does nothing with `cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr`, the child process' `stdout` and `stderr` go to the parent process' `stdout` and `stderr`.