# Start detached command with redirect to file

Tags: go, process, io

I'm trying to start a command in a detached process so that it can continue after go program exits. I need to redirect the output of the command to a file.

What I need is something like this:

```
func main() {
    command := exec.Command("/tmp/test.sh", ">", "/tmp/out")

    if err := command.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Command failed.", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Process ID:", command.Process.Pid)
}
```

Obviously such redirect doesn't work. As I immediately exit from the program after starting the long running command, I cannot open a file and bind it to the Stdout.

Is there any way to achieve such a redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918814/2728768

Opening a file (and `os.File` implements `io.Writer`), and then passing it as the `command.Stdout` could do the trick:

```
func main() {
    command := exec.Command("./tmp/test.sh")
    f, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/out", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // On this line you're going to redirect the output to a file
    command.Stdout = f
    if err := command.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Command failed.", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Process ID:", command.Process.Pid)
}
```

Not sure this could be a viable solution for your case. I've tried it locally and it seems working... remember that your user should be able to create/update the file.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. How does the process write to file after it's closed? If that doesn't matter why do we need to open it at all?

Comment: I didn't think about that. So, I'll investigate and come back to you, but I was reading the documentation and the exec.Cmd and the stdout we redirect is managed by a writer descriptor which, I believe, will take care of closing it (and it looks like opening it as well...): https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=6559:7169#L231

Answer (score 5):

You may start a shell which executes your command / app, and you may redirect its output to a file. The shell will continue to run and execute your script / app even if your Go app exits.

Example:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "/tmp/test.sh > /tmp/out")
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("Process ID:", cmd.Process.Pid)
```

Test it with this simple Go app (replace `/tmp/test.sh` with the name of the executable binary you compile this into):

```
package main
import ("fmt"; "time")
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d.: %v\n", i, time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

This app simply prints a line to the standard output once every second. You can see how the output file is being written e.g. with `tail -f /tmp/out`.

Note that you may use other shells to execute your scripts to your liking (and to what the `test.sh` script dictates).

For example to use `bash`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "/tmp/test.sh > /tmp/out")
// rest is unchanged
```

Note that the command to be executed by the shell is passed as a single `string` argument, and it is not broken down into multiple as you would do it if you were to execute it directly in the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although nothing wrong with yours, I'm going with the answer from @thoeni, because it's single solution for windows and linux which is more convenient for me.

Comment: This is good if we need to use the os provided stdOut and file redirection, After trigger no need an another go process running on top of the actual process. Thanks