# What is the difference between os.Stdout and os.File

Tags: linux, go

**I understand that `os.Stdout` points to the standard output of the system, it is actually a file pointer**

My understanding is that in theory `os.Stdout` and `os.File` should be interchangeable, and they both implement the `io.Writer` interface

But I have the following code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -f ~/test.log | grep h")

    //f, _ := os.OpenFile("tt.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_TRUNC, 0777)
    //defer f.Close()

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    //cmd.Stdout = f

    cmd.Start()

    cmd.Wait()
}

type testWriter struct {}

func (t *testWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    fmt.Println(p)

    return len(p), nil
}
```

This code works fine when I point `cmd.Stdout` to `os.Stdout`, but when I point `cmd.Stdout` to a file pointer, it cannot output anything

I don't understand why this is. Can someone tell me why `os.Stdout` works? Why is `os.File` not working?

I have tried other commands, such as `cat`, `ls`, and they all work normally

I have also tried to implement an `io.Writer` myself, but I cannot receive any content

I need help, please help me, thanks

UPDATE:

Thanks to @ElapsedSoul for the suggestion.

I understand that there is a buffer in the output of the file. I tried to refresh the buffer in two cases, but it didn't work. The code is as follows

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -f ~/test.log | grep h")

    //f, _ := os.OpenFile("tt.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_TRUNC, 0777)
    //defer f.Close()

    cmd.Stdout = &testWriter{}
    //cmd.Stdout = f

    cmd.Start()

    cmd.Wait()
}

type testWriter struct{}

func (t *testWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    os.Stdout.Write(p)
    os.Stdout.Sync()

    return len(p), nil
}
```

There is also the following way

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -f ~/test.log | grep h")

    f, _ := os.OpenFile("tt.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_TRUNC, 0777)
    defer f.Close()

    //cmd.Stdout = &testWriter{}
    cmd.Stdout = f
    
    go func() {
        for {
            f.Sync()
            
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    cmd.Start()

    cmd.Wait()
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about go,but in my opinio,the variable f is a file object,you can use some stream object or function of file object maybe like cmd.Stdout = f.write.

Comment: The return type of os.stdout or cmd.stdout is a stream object.The return type of os.file must be a file object.guess from an c++er

Comment: @ElapsedSoul In the Go language `cmd.Stdout` is an object that implements a specific interface `io.Writer`, both `os.Stdout` and `os.File` implement this interface, and `f.write` is a function pointer and cannot Assign to the `cmd.Stdout` object

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986943/in-golang-how-can-i-write-the-stdout-of-an-exec-cmd-to-a-file> ,I got this for your issue,maybe it's clear for you to understand. In my opinio if os.Openfile is similar to os.Create,maybe you need to find the function which can flush the stream buffer pool.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul Thank you, I understand the concept of buffers, and I have tried forced refresh. But it does not work, I updated the content of the question, you can learn more details

Comment: The grep command buffers output when stdout is not a terminal.  Use stdbuf or similar command to disable buffering in the grep command.  Also, check and handle the errors returned from os.Open, cmd.Start, and cmd.Wait.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you very much, it is indeed caused by the caching rules of the grep command. I checked `man grep` and added the `--line-buffered` option to get normal output.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If you are willing to answer this question, I will adopt your answer

Comment: @Luna Yeah,I got a knowledge point of grep by the following reply,too.Help you,Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grep command buffers output when stdout is not a terminal.

Use command flags (--line-buffered for grep) or the stdbuf command to disable output buffering.